# Doctrine 2.0 Caching and Defaults

Tags: php, caching, symfony1, doctrine-orm

Using Doctrine 2.x

A few if the entities in my domain are mapped to tables with only one row - this is to support additional complexity down the road (planned - so this does not fit YAGNI).

As an example consider the simple entity

```
Category\Type:
  type: entity
  table: category_type
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
```

In my application at the moment I only have one category type (name = 'regular'), but every time I create a new category (entity not shown - use your imagination; it has a N:1 relationship to Category\Type) I need to associate a type with the category. This means having to retrieve my single row from the database and then setting the association.

```
$category = new Category();
$type = $em->getRepository('Category\Type')->findByName('regular');
$category->setType($type);
$em->persist($category);
$em->flush();
```

I want to know how I can avoid doing this.

If I just use a new type like this...

```
$category = new Category();
$type = new Category\Type();
$type->setName('regular');
$category->setType($type);
$category->setId(1); // <-- This gets incremented anyway after the persist is called
$em->persist($category);
$em->flush();
```

Then doctrine tries to insert the type as a new entity (In fact it fails because the name column has an unique constraint in the database).

I've tried to do the above and then use merge

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities

But the same thing happens.

What am I missing here? How can I get doctrine to treat an new object as already being in the database, or how can I cache a managed entity at the code level.

Is it inappropriate to effectively 'cache' this in code - should I use one of the other caching mechanisms?

Comment: I think you cant. You need to make association to an existing object `Category\Type` when you create new one it will be... well *new one*, it will create a new row in DB and your association will point there you have to fetch the existing one. It is how doctrine is designed, you work with instances of objects, not rows in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original approach is the proper one.

```
$category = new Category();
$type = $em->getRepository('Category\Type')->findByName('regular');
$category->setType($type);
$em->persist($category);
$em->flush();
```

This is how Doctrine is designed.

What you try to do is to get(find) instance of the object by setting the name property to something that already exists. This is wrong. It is like calling your child John Lennon and expect it to resurrect Beatles.

Comment: Lol at the analogy - I s'pose I'll just hand it over to the other caching mechanisms then. I'll leave this open for a while longer before marking you correct.